# Filling out UITableView from JSON file

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I have the data from a local JSON file, and **need to fill out my `UITableView`.**  After

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return sports.count;
}
```

**I'm not sure how to fill out `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` + `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`**

Currently my code is as seen below, can you help?  Thanks!  Will post any extra as needed!

```
    NSArray *sports = JSONDictionary[@"sports"]; //array containing all sports (baseball, football, etc.)

    NSDictionary *baseball = sports[0]; //dictionary containing info about baseball

    NSArray *baseballLeagues = baseball[@"leagues"]; //array containing all leagues for baseball

    NSDictionary *MLB = baseballLeagues[0]; //dictionary for only the MLB league

    NSString *MLBName = MLB[@"name"]; //the full name of the MLB
```

I'm trying to get the Baseball league `name`s in the `UITableViewCell`s.

JSON.json:

```
{
    "sports": [{
               "name": "baseball",
               "id": 1
               },
               "leagues": [{
                           "name": "Major League Baseball",
                           "abbreviation": "mlb",
                           "id": 10,
                           "uid": "s:1~l:10",
                           "groupId": 9,
                           "shortName": "MLB",
                           "season": {
                           "year": 2014,
                           "type": 2,
                           "description": "regular",
                           "startDate": "2014-03-21T07:00:00Z",
                           "endDate": "2014-09-30T06:59:59Z"
                           },
                           "week": {
                           "number": 23,
                           "startDate": "2014-08-22T07:00:00Z",
                           "endDate": "2014-08-29T06:59:00Z"
                           }
                           }, {
                           "name": "Men's College Baseball",
                           "abbreviation": "college-baseball",
                           "id": 14,
                           "groupId": 14,
                           "shortName": "NCAA Men's Baseball"
                           }]
               },
```

Comment: One side note- I would expect that your JSON would be different as well. Wouldn't each sport have a sport array *inside* it?

Comment: Here is my full JSON file if you'd like to take a look; but basically this view controller you see the leagues, and then based on which league you pick (MLB) the next ViewController will show the teams that are in the league but sadly it is a totally different JSON file.  https://gist.github.com/lllovesmatt/a98cec323fc8b6f69d9e

Comment: Do not vandalise your questions after others have taken their time to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would implement this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [sports[section][@"leagues"] count]; //returns the number of leagues in each sport
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *leagueName = sports[indexPath.section][@"leagues"][indexPath.row][@"name"];

    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = leagueName;
    return cell;
}
```

This solution would set the table view up so that each sport has it's own section, and in those sections are cells containing the names of each league in that sport.

Comment: This looks really close to what I was using before I had to switch to a local JSON file (was using dynamic http json from an API before).  Looks close right?  https://gist.github.com/lllovesmatt/9b51e61ebe46e40bae80

Comment: Yes and you can keep the old code. The only difference is how you obtain the JSON, so if it's the same you can only change the code where you retrieve the JSON.

Comment: How I obtain it is different because its local and not http.  And also I had model classes set up before and I'm not sure if that works with how i obtain the JSON now ya know?  It wasn't working when I tried before at least

Comment: Well, I would have to see the rest of your code to help you with that. Did this code work for you, though?

Comment: Not yet, but I'm going to keep tweaking it here real quick because I'm sure its something that I've got thats really small and my fault.  What other code would be helpful?

Comment: I added the code to create the cell, if that's where you were having an issue.

Comment: It's giving me this right now when it crashes: `reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ae1ff60'`

Comment: And for some reason for `    return [sports[section][@"leagues"] count]; //returns the number of leagues in each sport` its giving me an error of `Use of undeclared identifier section`

Comment: That's strange. Try doing `[[[sports objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"leagues"] count]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59903/discussion-between-chris-loonam-and-lbase).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS - Here is a working implementation of what it seems you want to do, which produces the following result:

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *baseball = @{
                               @"name": @"baseball",
                               @"leagues": @[@{@"name": @"Major League Baseball"}, @{@"name": @"Men's College Baseball"}]
                               };

    NSDictionary *football = @{
                               @"name": @"football",
                               @"leagues": @[@{@"name": @"National Football League"}, @{@"name": @"NCAA Football"}]
                               };

    NSDictionary *basketball = @{
                               @"name": @"basketball",
                               @"leagues": @[@{@"name": @"National Basketball Assoc."}, @{@"name": @"Women's National Basketball Assoc"}, @{@"name": @"NCAA Basketball"}]
                               };

    // instead of hard-coding in everything like I just did for testing, this should be
    // your JSON
    _sports= @[baseball, football, basketball];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // return the number of sports, as each sport gets its own section
    return _sports.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // get the sport for this section
    NSDictionary *sport = _sports[section];

    // get the array of leagues for that sport
    NSArray *leaguesForSport = sport[@"leagues"];

    // return the number of leagues in the leagues array for this section
    return leaguesForSport.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // get the sport for this section
    NSDictionary *sport = _sports[indexPath.section];

    // get the sport's leagues array
    NSArray *leaguesForSport = sport[@"leagues"];

    // get the league for this row
    NSDictionary *league = leaguesForSport[indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    // if we couldn't reuse a cell, create one
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    // now customize the cell based on the league information
    cell.textLabel.text = league[@"name"];

    // return the cell
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSDictionary *sport = _sports[section];
    return sport[@"name"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't appear his data model reflects this, and there is no indication that he is using properties or instance variables, so your solution doesn't address that. You would think there would be an array of leagues for each sport, but if you look at his JSON it appears there's multiple sports "objects" but a single array of leagues separate from each sport. The leagues array should be nested inside the sport object. In other words, the sports object should have name, id, and a leagues array. There are multiple issues here at first glance, but I need to step away for a bit.

Comment: Yup this makes sense.  The only part I'm trying to figure out is the second to last line `cell.textLabel.text = leagueName;`, where do I get the `leagueName`?  I'm going to update my question with my current code right now so you can see what I did so far

Comment: Look at my code, a few lines above that is where I create it.

Comment: Yup I'm getting MLB and College Baseball in the tableview now, but its doing them multiple times because its taking the sports count number of rows... Hmmm

Comment: I want the tableView rows to show all of the leagues in every sport https://gist.github.com/lllovesmatt/a98cec323fc8b6f69d9e

Comment: And also, this is my fault for not explaining and showing code enough for you to have known that probably

Comment: I'm going to see if I can replicate the data and get it working for you. Should be a few minutes.

Comment: Perhaps, but to what degree? It is clear there is a slight lack of understanding here regarding how the data structures are laid out/accessed, and while my solution is trivially less efficient, it demonstrates what is actually happening in a more clear way with each array/dictionary.

Comment: It could also be argued that, in general, doing it in perhaps a more verbose way as I did is clearer and easier to follow, for the developer writing the code or anyone reviewing/working with it later on, rather than nesting everything.

Comment: What do you mean declaring multiple arrays in the header? This entire process only requires one instance variable _sports.

Comment: @Mike I'm gonna come back in two days when I can do a bounty and give you bounty points to say thanks for the help!  I appreciate the help so much man!